# Limit of the form 0 times infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

I'm trying to evaluate  $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^3\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)$.

It's $0\cdot\infty$ situation. I know that indeterminate forms can sometimes be evaluated using L'Hopital's rule. I would prefer not to use L'Hopitals rule as there is a factorial and I'm not sure about the next steps.

Are there any methods that can be used to evaluate this kind of limit or any tips on how should I continue?

Comment: Welcome. The Hopital's rule not exist in the sequences if $n\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deduce from L'Hopital's Rule that$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log\left(1+x\right)}{x^3}=0,$$which implies that$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^3\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)=0.$$But$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):0\leqslant n^3\log\left(1+\frac1{n!}\right)\leqslant n^3\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)$$and so…

Comment: Can we use expansion of log $(1+x)$, here $x=\frac{1}{n!}$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3}{n!}-\frac{n^3}{2 (n!)^2}+\cdots=0$?

Comment: That's tricky. Yes, the limit of each $\frac{n^3}{k(n!)^k}$ is $0$; but how to deduce from this that the limit of the sum is $0$ too?

Comment: Each term would be zero, so total sum adds upto zero? Isn't this always the case? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong:\begin{align}1&=1+0+0+0+0+\cdots\\&=\frac12+\frac12+0+0+0+0+\cdots\\&=\frac13+\frac13+\frac13+0+0+\cdots\\&=\vdots\end{align}

Comment: Here, each term is not zero but? Sorry, I didn't understand this example.  $\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots$, so each term in the above case would be zero.

Comment: This is an example of a series $\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{mn}$ in which $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{mn}=0$ but in which $\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{mn}\neq0$.

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I understood.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^3\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n^3 \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n^3 \cdot 0 = 0$ ... is it a good way to evaluate the given limit?

Comment: No, since it gives you $\infty\times0$, which is an indetermination.

Comment: Thanks a lot. ... and can we do $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3}{n!} = 1$?  Is it an indetermination as well or this is a different case?

Comment: It is also an indetermination, but, in this case, the limit is equal to $0$.

Comment: What has this to do with your original question? Is there something in my answer that you find wrong or inappropriate?

Comment: If $n\geqslant4$, then $n!\geqslant n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$ and therefore $0\leqslant\frac{n^3}{n!}\leqslant\frac{n^3}{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}$. So, by the squeeze theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3}{n!}=0$.

Comment: I see. Thank you, I really appreaciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

You may proceed as follows:

You have

$$n^3\ln (1+\frac 1{n!})= \frac{n^3}{n!}\ln (1+\frac 1{n!})^{n!}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\cdot 1=0$$

Here, I use $\lim_{m\to \infty}(1+\frac 1m)^m = e$ and $\ln e = 1$.

Comment: Can we use expansion of log $(1+x)$, here $x=\frac{1}{n!}$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3}{n!}-\frac{n^3}{2 (n!)^2}+\cdots=0$?

Comment: @s1mple : Yes, for example as follows: $n^3\ln (1+\frac 1{n!})= \frac{n^3}{n!}\frac{\ln (1+\frac 1{n!})}{\frac 1{n!}}\sim \frac{n^3}{n!}$

Comment: @s1mple : But what you suggest is an unjustified interchange of limit operations:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k(n) \stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}a_k(n)$$

I recommend to check out this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interchange_of_limiting_operations
 
In the present case this interchange works but such an interchange of limits is an operation which has to be justified and is not a general rule which always works.

Comment: Yes. that's also a valid point. Thanks for the help.